# How can I get a key from an object by its value?

Tags: javascript

I am working in react. I have a constant like

```
const priorityMap = {
 "medium":"clean",
 "high":"breaker",
 "low":"promote"
}
```

If I do the following , I am getting result.

```
const map1 = priorityMap["medium"];
console.log("print checkgroup  " + map1)
```

But I want to do the reverse thing. My input is "clean" and I want to retrieve "medium". Is there any way to fetch the key?

Answer (score 0):

It would be :

```
const valueToSearch = "clean"
const result = Object.entries(priorityMap).find(entry => entry[1] === valueToSearch)[1]
```